# Using Web Audio API with React

Tags: reactjs, web-audio-api

Consider the following React component. This is what i do: two buttons are rendered, "voice" and "delay". When I press Voice button, the microphone is accessed, and Delay button toggles Delay effect on and off. At a current state, the code works, but I run into some problems. For instance, the color of delay button is rendered conditionally, and depends on the value of echoDelay.isApplied(). This does not work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { hide_fmSynth } from "./fmSynthSlice";
import "./fmSynth.css";

const voiceComponent = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { display } = useSelector((state) => state.fmSynth);
    const [microphoneStarted, setMicrophoneStarted] = useState(false);
    const [delayIsOn, setDelayIsOn] = useState(false);

    let audioContext = new AudioContext();
    let primaryGainControl = audioContext.createGain();
    primaryGainControl.gain.setValueAtTime(0.35, 0);
    let echoDelay = createEchoDelayEffect(audioContext);
    primaryGainControl.connect(audioContext.destination);

    const voiceInput = async () => {
        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: true,
            });
            let microphoneSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            echoDelay.placeBetween(microphoneSource, primaryGainControl);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("something wrong with microphone", error);
        }
    };

    function createEchoDelayEffect(ctx) {
        const delay = ctx.createDelay(1);
        const dryNode = ctx.createGain();
        const wetNode = ctx.createGain();
        const mixer = ctx.createGain();
        const filter = ctx.createBiquadFilter();

        delay.delayTime.value = 0.75;
        dryNode.gain.value = 1;
        wetNode.gain.value = 0;
        filter.frequency.value = 1100;
        filter.type = "highpass";

        return {
            apply: function () {
                wetNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.75, ctx.currentTime);
            },
            discard: function () {
                wetNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, ctx.currentTime);
            },
            isApplied: function () {
                return wetNode.gain.value > 0;
            },
            placeBetween: function (inputNode, outputNode) {
                inputNode.connect(delay);
                delay.connect(wetNode);
                wetNode.connect(filter);
                filter.connect(delay);

                inputNode.connect(dryNode);
                dryNode.connect(mixer);
                wetNode.connect(mixer);
                mixer.connect(outputNode);
            },
        };
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (microphoneStarted) {
            voiceInput();
        }
        return;
    }, [microphoneStarted]);

    if (display) {
        return (
            <section className="pad">
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        dispatch(hide_fmSynth());
                    }}
                >
                    x
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        setMicrophoneStarted(!microphoneStarted);
                    }}
                >
                    voice
                </button>
                <button
                    id="delay"
                    onClick={() => {
                        // setDelayIsOn(!delayIsOn);
                        if (echoDelay.isApplied()) {
                            echoDelay.discard();
                            console.log(echoDelay.isApplied());
                        } else {
                            echoDelay.apply();
                            console.log(echoDelay.isApplied());
                        }
                    }}
                    // style={delayIsOn ? { color: "red" } : {}}
                    style={echoDelay.isApplied() ? { color: "red" } : {}}
                >
                    delay
                </button>
            </section>
        );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};

export default voiceComponent;
```

I added console logs that clearly show this value switching between true and false, and obviously so – I can hear delay effect being turned on and off, but the button stays black. I tried adding delayIsOn variable, and toggling it with setState, but this brings out another issue – the component gets re-rendered, which messes up my delay effect: it either doesn't turn on, or doesn't turn off.

Long story short, I can make React work, or I can make Web Audio API work, but not both at the same time, I just cant wrap my head around all the renders and re-renders and what brakes what. If anyone would explain what is going on here, or point me to any resources where this gets explained, I would be infinitely grateful.

Thanks to everyone in advance

Comment: For the delay onClick I would define that with `useCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to figure it out!

In short, audio context should be defined somewhere **outside** React component to avoid unexpected behavior due to re-renders.

The relationship between Web Audio API and React is thoroughly explained in [this youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQ1Pnjr9zvi4x9sofuSjF6fcjjRT222In).

Below is the solution for my original problem ([for some reason doesn't work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76430765/unable-to-acces-microphone-in-chrome-using-navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia)):

```
import { useState } from "react";

// create audio context
const actx = new AudioContext();
const out = actx.destination;
// create output gain node
const outputGain = actx.createGain();
outputGain.gain.value = 0.5;
outputGain.connect(out);
// create echo delay node
const echoDelay = createEchoDelayEffect(actx);
// value to soften parameter changes
const easing = 0.005;

//function to access microphone on buton click:
const init = async () => {
    function success(stream) {
        let mediaStreamSource = actx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        // plug audio stream from  mic into signal chain
        echoDelay.placeBetween(mediaStreamSource, outputGain);
    }

    //access user microphone
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
        .then(success)
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
        });
};

//function to create delay node
function createEchoDelayEffect(ctx) {
    const delay = ctx.createDelay(1);
    const dryNode = ctx.createGain();
    const wetNode = ctx.createGain();
    const mixer = ctx.createGain();
    const filter = ctx.createBiquadFilter();

    delay.delayTime.value = 0.75;
    dryNode.gain.value = 1;
    wetNode.gain.value = 0;
    filter.frequency.value = 1100;
    filter.type = "highpass";

    return {
        apply: function () {
            wetNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.75, ctx.currentTime);
        },
        discard: function () {
            wetNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, ctx.currentTime);
        },
        isApplied: function () {
            return wetNode.gain.value > 0;
        },
        placeBetween: function (inputNode, outputNode) {
            inputNode.connect(delay);
            delay.connect(wetNode);
            wetNode.connect(filter);
            filter.connect(delay);

            inputNode.connect(dryNode);
            dryNode.connect(mixer);
            wetNode.connect(mixer);
            mixer.connect(outputNode);
        },
        delayTime: function () {
            return delay.delayTime.value;
        },
        wetNodeGain: function () {
            return wetNode.gain.value;
        },
        changeTime: function (newTime) {
            delay.delayTime.linearRampToValueAtTime(newTime, easing);
        },
        changeWetGain: function (newGain) {
            wetNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(newGain, easing);
        },
    };
}

function App() {
    const [delayGain, setDelayGain] = useState(echoDelay.wetNodeGain());
    const changeDelayGain = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        setDelayGain(value);
        echoDelay.changeWetGain(value);
    };

    const [delayTime, setDelayTime] = useState(echoDelay.delayTime);
    const changeDelayTime = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        setDelayTime(value);
        echoDelay.changeTime(value);
    };

    const [outputGainVal, setOutputGainVal] = useState(outputGain.gain.value);
    const changeVolume = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        setOutputGainVal(value);
        outputGain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(value, actx.currentTime + easing);
    };

    return (
        <div
            className="App"
            style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", width: "200px" }}
        >
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    init();
                }}
            >
                voice
            </button>
            {/* delay gain control */}
            <label htmlFor="delay-gain">{"delay gain: " + delayGain}</label>
            <input
                type="range"
                id="delay-gain"
                name="delay-gain"
                min="0"
                max="1"
                step="0.1"
                value={delayGain}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    changeDelayGain(e);
                }}
            />
            {/* delay time control */}
            <label htmlFor="delay-time">{"delay time: " + delayTime}</label>
            <input
                type="range"
                id="delay-time"
                name="delay-time"
                min="0"
                max="1"
                step="0.1"
                value={delayTime}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    changeDelayTime(e);
                }}
            />
            {/* output gain contol */}
            <label htmlFor="output-gain">{"output gain: " + outputGainVal}</label>
            <input
                type="range"
                id="output-gain"
                name="output-gain"
                min="0"
                max="1"
                step="0.1"
                value={outputGain}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    changeVolume(e);
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```