# Unable to acces microphone in Chrome using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, web-audio-api, microphone, getusermedia

I am trying to access a microphone in my react app using this code:

```
// create audio context
const actx = new AudioContext();

// oscillator to check that audio context works
const osc = actx.createOscillator();
osc.connect(actx.destination);

//function to access microphone
const voice = async () => {
    function success(stream) {
        let mediaStreamSource = actx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        console.log(mediaStreamSource);
        mediaStreamSource.connect(actx.destination);
    }

    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
        .then(success)
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
        });
};

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    osc.start();
                }}
            >
                START OSC
            </button>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    osc.stop();
                }}
            >
                STOP OSC
            </button>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    voice();
                }}
            >
                VOICE
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

It looks like there should be no problem, and there isn't... **In Firefox and Safari everything works** as expected – **but not in Chrome.**

When I press 'VOICE' button in Chrome, it requests microphone access, I click allow, the microphone icon appears and a thingy starts to blink indicating that microphone works... but I hear nothing. Even more weird is that it works once, when I load the app the very first time, but then stops working. I noticed this, and then were able to recreate it when I loaded the app in Chromium.

So please could anyone explain what is going on here?)

Honestly, I'm kind of out of ideas. The code should work, and it did in other projects. I don't know what I'm overlooking here.